# Use Sqlite JDBC when the programm is exportet in JARs (Intellij)

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea, jar

I am writing my code in Intellij and created a Sqlite Database for some data. I connected it with the sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar driver inside of intellij and can run it successfully there.

When I create a JAR (or multiple Jars because of the Modules) and start the programm, I get this error message:

> java -jar ServerAbschalteHotline.jar java.sql.SQLException: No
>   suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:src/Resources/credentials.db at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270) at
>   com.company.SQLiteHandler.connect(SQLiteHandler.java:20) at
>   com.company.SQLiteHandler.getCredentials(SQLiteHandler.java:30) at
>   com.company.HttpsServer.makeServer(HttpsServer.java:64) at
>   com.company.Main.main(Main.java:21)

So for me it looks like the programm couldnt find the driver after it get exported. I checked that the .jar file is there (with all the other .jar files) and tried to include it as a libary too.

[image: Folder with all the jars]
[image: Jar included in libaries]

**I guess I missed one place where I have to add the jar, so where is it?**

Comment: Is sqlite JAR exist in your project JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a clean jar (downloaded the same version of the jar from the same page) and a recompiling solved the problem. I dont know where the real problem was, maybe the jar contains error(s)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but when creating the jar I make sure that the JDBC driver is included.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]